# Regaining Path Property After Match Operator in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So, I have been working on the following code for awhile, and I have had some great help here that I am thankful for.  This code will open a Word or Text document, pull out the particular pattern, and return the number. Now, the only problem I am having is that I cannot figure out how to return the actual filename with full path after the utilization of the match operator.  All that I am left with is the actual numbers that match the range.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$SearchStandard = @('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}' )
$NOMATCH = @('235-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}')
$NOMATCH2 = @('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}')
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$allword  = Get-childitem -recurse *.docx , *.txt 
$newobj = New-Object -com word.application
Foreach ($wd in $allword) {
    $docu = $newobj.Documents.Open($wd.fullname, $false, $true)
    $docu.Paragraphs | ForEach-Object {
        ForEach ($SearchText in $SearchStandard) {
            $_.Range.Text | Where-Object {($_ -match $SearchText) -and ($_-notmatch $NOMATCH) -and ($_-notmatch $NOMATCH2)} 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly hint: If you're thankful for the great help you've received, consider accepting the answers that have solved your problems in the past, by clicking the checkmark on the left of the appropriate answers

Comment: You should firstly do proper indenting. Since you first match $SearchStandard, $NOMATCH2 doesn't make sense since they differ in the places.

Comment: @LotPings `-match` v `-notmatch`. '153-54-8645' would satisfy all three conditions, whereas '1503-54-8645' would match `$SearchText`, but _also_ match `$NOMATCH2` and therefore shouldn't come through

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `$NOTMATCH2` has 3 numbers after the first hyphen thus my hint.

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice. Still depends on the input strings in the document (ie. could there be more than one number on a line?)

Comment: Thank you Mathias and LotPings.  Mathias, indeed, I will start clicking the checkmark.  Also, yes, it is possible that there is more than one number on a line.

Comment: You are both geniuses:)  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a calculated property to reference `$wd.FullName`:

```
$_.Range.Text | Where-Object {
    ($_ -match$SearchText) -and 
    ($_-notmatch $NOMATCH) -and 
    ($_-notmatch $NOMATCH2)
} | Select-Object @{Label='Number';Expression={$_}},@{Label='Path';Expression={$wd.FullName}}
```